# How does rotation and scale affect a point lamp?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I am designing a scene in Blender, for the lighting I am using a point lamp which has rotation properties.  I tried to rotate it to check the effect of the rotation on the quality of shadows, but I do not see any effect.

Comment: The transforms are embedded for every object - with what data is this object filled is another thing. Some objects have mesh data, some have camera data and some are just empties. The object is just an container with the ability to transform. If you have really a point light with no dimensions, then the transforms are meaningless on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It doesn't** - rotation and scale have no effect on a point light.

A point light emits light uniformly in all directions, so rotating it does nothing.  Note that if you change the lamp to any other type (*Sun*, *Spot*, *Hemi*, or *Area*) rotation will affect the direction of the light.

---

Scale also has no effect on the output of the lamp.  This can be demonstrated by trying to apply the scale of the lamp wth <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, which will throw an error: `Objects have no data to transform`.

Note that if you change the lamp to an *Area* lamp, scale **will** affect the size of the lamp.  Scaling a *Hemi* lamp to very small values has a strange result, it seems to take much longer to render and produce drastically more noise on the first few samples, but not really change the actual lighting pattern.

Comment: Using cycles, if you change the size of a pint light it will make the shadow softer.

Comment: @cegaton RIght, *Size* - not scale.  I initially thought that scale would scale the Size, but I did some testing and it seems to not do so.

Comment: Thanks very very much for this answer. I thought I was going crazy when area lights scaled properly and point lights didn't :).