# Point Lamp cannot be rotated - Need confirmation

Tags: 3d-view, light, lighting, 3d-cursor

I am using R and trying to rotate the point lamp, but it does not. I came across this answer - [Point Lamp Rotate Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/how-does-rotation-and-scale-affect-a-point-lamp)

I have a noob confusion - Doesn't a point lamp correspond to light TO A POINT, so ideally if I rotate it, it should have corresponding effect of the light source to THE point. So ideally we should be able to rotate the light source i.e Point Lamp?

Kindly help me understand.

Thanks

Comment: no, it's a lamp which emits around it. Maybe try a Spot if you want to light a particular point.

Comment: Point lamp is a lamp that emits from a point in all directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point lamp in Blender is an object that emits light from a single point to all directions. It is impossible to rotate a single point - it remains the same. You can rotate it around some other pivot like for example around the 3d Cursor, however it will only effect the location of the point light. It makes sense for it to have rotation properties, because the type of Lamp can be changed so if another type of lamp is rotated and then changed to a Point lamp it would loose the rotation information otherwise, while right now the information is kept and it can be changed back to any of the directional types pointing at the same direction.

Comment: The Point Lamp retaining the properties to pass it on, if the lamp type is changed makes sense. Thanks for the input.